# URL re-writing in PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to implement URL rewriting in my PHP application. Can someone share a step by step procedure of implementing URL rewriting in PHP

In my application I want to implement following URL rewriting

```
http://example.com/fast-five
http://example.com/300
http://example.com/13-b
```

from

```
http://example.com/movie-download.php?nm=fast-five
http://example.com/movie-download.php?nm=300
http://example.com/movie-download.php?nm=13-b
```

**One more thing** which URL will be best according to SEO, management, application point-of-view out of the following two types.

Comment: the correct way to do this involves zero php. htaccess is sufficient

Comment: For apache: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Comment: [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a great place to ask about SEO benefits, FYI.

Comment: See [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good .htaccess/mod_rewrite/url-rewriting tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426056/good-htaccess-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you serving your PHP through an Apache HTTP Server installation?  If so:

```
RewriteRule ^/fast-five$ /movie-download.php?nm=fast-five [R=301]
```

From an SEO perspective, the first would be preferred.  Using the HTTP 301 ("Moved Permanently") is most effective for this.

Answer (score 3):

Of course

```
http://example.com/fast-five
```

will be good for SEO

Answer (score 0):

If your using an MVC framework like CakePHP, you should look at the [documentation on routing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration).  Otherwise, you can use the web servers [rewriting rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).